# MIPS store byte

Tags: mips

I have a problem with this code. It should do this:
gabriele -> grl
but instead of 3 characters it redouble the last one. Hence: gabriele -> grll
Why?

```
    .data 0x10010000
nome:       .asciiz "gabriele"
voc:        .asciiz "aeiou"
st_nome:    

    .text 0x400000
main:       la $s1, voc         #address of voc in s1
            la $s2, nome        #address di nome in s2
            li $t3, 0           #index name
            li $t4, 0           #index  vowel
            li $t5, 0           #memory index
            li $a1, 4           #max number of character

cerca_nom:  lbu $t0, nome($t3)
            beqz, $t0, fine

sc_voc2:    lbu $t1, voc($t4)
            beq $t0, $t1, ignora2
            addi $t4, $t4, 1
            beqz $t1, salva_n
            j sc_voc2

salva_n:    sb $t0, st_nome($t5) 
            addiu $t5, $t5, 1
            bge $t5, $a1, prime

ignora2:    addi $t3, $t3, 1
            li $t4, 0
            j cerca_nom

prime:      li $t5, 0                   
            la $t1, st_nome

            lbu $t0, 0($t1)             
            sb $t0, st_nome($t5)        #take the first character
            addi $t5, $t5, 1

            lbu $t0, 2($t1)
            sb $t0, st_nome($t5)        #take the third character
            addi $t5, $t5, 1

            lbu $t0, 3($t1)
            sb $t0, st_nome($t5)        #take the fourth character

fine:
```

Comment: The code you've posted can not be used to reproduce the problem because parts of your program are missing.

Comment: Well, for one, there's a jump to a label named `fine`, but there's no `fine:` label in the code you've posted.

Comment: Ah no, it's an empty label. It's the end of this "program". I'm going to edit, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `cerca_nom` loop you're removing the vowels from the name and storing the remaining characters (`'g'`, `'b'`, `'r'`, `'l'`) at `st_nome`.

So now you've got `'gbrl'` at `st_nome`.

Then you do:

```
st_nome[0] = st_nome[0]   ; still 'gbrl'
st_nome[1] = st_nome[2]   ; 'grrl'
st_nome[2] = st_nome[3]   ; 'grll'
```

You're never overwriting `st_nome[3]`, so there will still be an `'l'` there.

Comment: How can I solve it? Could I use a temporary area and save there all remaning characters and use "sb" to put the first, third and fourth character in another area?

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to solve(?). You've got the correct characters (`'grl`) starting at `st_nome`. Why does it matter what the next byte after that is? If you need to pass the string to the `print_string` syscall, just write zero to that byte.